# How to influence the day/light cycle?

Tags: just-cause-2

It doesn't seem to conform to the real time clock and I hate driving in the dark. What should I do to change it to day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot edit stuff like that in SP, however;

If you play JC:MP then you can program your server for the time to be frozen at all times.

See here for more info:

> http://www.jc-mp.com/

Comment: I am on the Xbox. Sorry for the lack of info.

Comment: Then it is not possible even with the help of 3rd party tools.. sorry!